# Promise and Timeout in .net core to wait x seconds

Tags: c#

I would like to know if is possible to do this in .net core

Typescript code:

```
await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 10000));
```

I try with but this is not the same.

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

Maybe this is better?

```
await Task.Delay(10000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C# equivalent is `await Task.Delay(10000);`

`Task.Delay` returns a task (i.e., promise) that completes after the specified time.

Comment: Thank you. Then my assumption was correct.